# sending messages to celery by plain rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a rabbitmq client written in js and have a running in python celery . Can I send a message to rabittmq queue and run a task in celery with it?

JS rabbitmq code:

```
 const callbackOnMsg = (msg: Message | null) => {
     if (msg?.properties?.correlationId == correlationId){
         const fileId = msg.content.toString();
         console.log('[.] Got %s', fileId);
         resolve(fileId);
     }
 }

 this.rabbitmqChannel.consume(
     config.RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME_FILES_CREATE_RPC_CALLBACK,
     callbackOnMsg,
     {noAck: true}
 );

 this.rabbitmqChannel.sendToQueue(
     config.RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME_FILES_CREATE_RPC_SEND,
     Buffer.from(messageToSend)
     {
         correlationId: correlationId,
         replyTo: config.RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME_FILES_CREATE_RPC_CALLBACK
     }
 );
```

Python celery code:

```
celery_app = celery.Celery(
    'tasks',
    backend='rpc://',
    broker=CelerySettings().get_conn_string()
)

class FileInStorageCreateTask(FileStorageTask):
    name = "db_builder.celery_.task_file_create"

    @async_to_sync
    async def run(self, file_type: str, encoded_file_data: str) -> str:
        ...  # some code


# Trying to listen 'files_create_rpc_send' queue
celery_app.conf.update(
    task_routes={'db_builder.celery_.*': {'queue': 'files_create_rpc_send'}},
    task_default_queue='files_create_rpc_send',
)
```

Run celery command:

```
celery -A db_builder.celery_ worker -l INFO -Q files_create_rpc_send
```

Celery config on startup (you can see the queue has been added):

```
 -------------- celery@oleg-Aspire-A715-42G v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-6.2.0-33-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.37 2023-09-28 15:43:05
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7f7f5238eb90
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://rabbitmq:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> files_create_rpc_send exchange=files_create_rpc_send(direct) key=files_create_rpc_send
                

[tasks]
  . db_builder.celery_.task_file_create
```

Error in celery when js client adds message to queue:

```
Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?
The full contents of the message body was: body: '{"type":"Create","tempFileName":"./temp-files/temp_7098725d-0390-49b5-bd9b-ed67233a1337","filetype":"image/jpeg"}' (134b)
{content_type:None content_encoding:None
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None4', 'delivery_tag': 1, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'files_create_rpc_send'} headers={}}
```